# How to fix error "OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, redis

My rails app is hosted with heroku and they recently updated the redis version my app was using from 4.0.14 to 6.2. This has caused some bugs to start appearing of the following nature:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 peeraddr=108.128.159.63:20459 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
```

From other stackoverflow articles (eg. [Herkou Redis - certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66246528/herkou-redis-certificate-verify-failed-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate)) I've updated my config for `config/initializers/redis.rb`:

```
if Rails.env.test?
  require "mock_redis"
  REDIS = MockRedis.new
else
  REDIS = Redis.new(url: ENV["REDIS_URL"], ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE })
end
```

and have also updated `config/cable.yml` to:

```
development:
  adapter: async

test:
  adapter: test

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: good_gym_production
  ssl_params:
    verify_mode: <%= OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE %>
```

To try and specify that no verification is needed, but this hasn't worked so far. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My bad I missed a bit in heroku's guide regarding connecting Redis to Sidekiq. I just had to add an initializer at `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` :

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = {
    url: ENV["REDIS_URL"],
    ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE }
  }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = {
      url: ENV["REDIS_URL"],
      ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE }
  }
end
```

I don't think Heroku's [guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-redis) is the clearest but should have seen that